# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<MyWidget>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, iterable

After migrating to null safety, the migration tool added `as Iterable<SetWidget>` to my code. But unfortunately i get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<SetWidget>' in type cast
```

This is the code:

```
  final List<Widget> _sets = [];

  Map getSets() {
    Map sets = {};
    int k = 0;
    for (SetWidget set in _sets as Iterable<SetWidget>) {
      sets.putIfAbsent(k.toString(), () => set.getMap());
      k++;
    }
    return sets;
  }
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why the tool decided to do that, but if you think about it, it obviously throws an error. `_sets` is a list of Widgets, which means it could include for example a Column, a Container, and a `SetWidget`, so it can't be cast to a SetWidget iterable.

is `getMap()` a method in the `SetWidget` class? if it is, could you change the `List<Widget>` to a `List<SetWidget>` and remove the `as Iterable<SetWidget>`? Hopefully, that solves your problem.

Also, side note, what is this code for? Are you turning a list into a `Map<String, Function>` where the string is just an index? if you are, why not use a list instead?

```
for (SetWidget widget in _sets)
{
  sets.add(widget.getMap)
}
```

Comment: Also helped me.. Thank you